# XSLT Transformation (performance related query)

Tags: xslt

I am doing the transformation of an xml document using the following code snippet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('POC.XML')/a/b/Outputs/*">
  <ns0:xyz xmlns:ns0="http://ratabase.cgi.com/">
    <ns0:na>
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
    </ns0:na>
    <ns0:Val>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </ns0:Val>
  </ns0:Rat>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I would like to know if there is any performance hit using (`<xsl:for-each select="document('POC.XML')/a/b/Outputs/*">`) using the document function in conjunction with the for-each statement when used in large scale applications?

One approach that I am using to transform the xml is by using the syntax given below:

```
<xsl:variable name="var:xmldoc" select="document('POC.XML')/a/b/c/d/Outputs"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="$var:xmldoc"/>
```

I would also like to know whether any alternate methods are applicable to accomplish the above transformation.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT WHEN POSTING HERE. Also. to post code like XSLT, select it with the mouse and then hit the `{}` button just above the editor.

Comment: Try also to provide meaningful parts of code, if possible and, in the xml case, well-formed.

Comment: Is it just me or does a namespace prefix on a variable name seem strange?

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends entirely on the XSLT processor you are using; there's no point asking a performance question without saying what processor you are asking about. I would expect most XSLT processors to handle this construct quite efficiently (they certainly won't parse the document repeatedly) - but there may be exceptions.

If you want to know whether one construct is faster than another, then measure it. There's no point speculating about performance - if you can't measure the difference, then there isn't a difference to worry about.

You second code sample is pretty obscure. OK, you select some nodes and then you copy them. You don't say why you are copying them - usually in XSLT you don't need to copy things, because you can work just as well with the original.